# JButton on bottom of window

Tags: java, swing

I'm getting back into swing after not doing it for a while.
What's the best way to have fixed sized button stay in the center , bottom of my window?
If I use Borderlayout.south it makes the button too wide. I can't remember the trick

Comment: Did you try calling `button.setPreferredSize(Dimension)` when using BorderLayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally two ways to handle this.

- Nesting, I.e. Create a panel with border layout.  Create another panel with flow layout to add your button to.  Put the second panel in the south of the first panel
- Use a more sophisticated layout such as [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Look into using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It's incredibly handy using Swing.

```
  int buttonWidth = 100;
  int buttonHeight = 50;
  button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
  this.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0"));
  this.add(button, "pos 50%-" + buttonWidth/2 + " 100%-" + buttonHeight);
```

There might be an easier way with a core layout manager, or even an easier way with MigLayout, but that would be the way I would approach it at first.

Another alternative would be to use a null layout and `setBounds` whenever the parent panel's size changes. Most Swing programmers would advise against a null layout, in which case you could look at `BoxLayout`. It's entirely up to you, but I find `MigLayout` indispensable.

Comment: `Most Swing programmers would advise against a null layout` == Swing GUI isn't designated for usage of AbsoluteLayout & ComponentListener, why supply standard LayoutManagers or todays Custom LayoutManagers this way, +1 for 3rd. party MigLayout